# How to arrange Airflow Dags in the UI tidy in folders?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm using Airflow version 1.9.0, and I'm gonna have hundreds of Dags. is there a way to arrange the Airflow UI with folders, sub folders, and only then to put the Dags in it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The UI doesn't ship with that, but you can use the search bar to filter out what DAGs you're seeing. For instance you can type in your Owner name if you just want to see your own DAGs.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is make a consistent naming convention for `dag_id`, such as:

```
project1_workflow1_startdate1
project1_workflow2_startdate1
```

Answer (score 0):

From version 1.10.8 you can use tags: [tags](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/add-dag-tags.html)

Comment: Could you tell us why Tags can solve this issue?

Comment: It doesn't solve this issue completely. But tags are really useful. You can filter by one or multiple tags. And you can share URL to dags with certain tags.